# HTML Button that opens a panel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing a school project (with 3 other people) and we decided to make a game. We are just in the starting phase, but I am stuck on a problem.

I want that a button in the footer opens up a panel in which there is a title and some text.

I am sorry for the ugly colours and lay-out, it's just all placeholding stuff:

So, [this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3HZS.gif) needs to open a panel which [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqpqT.gif).

Comment: What's the question? Where's your code showing effort and progress?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If you want to change something on an event (in this case `click`) you'll need to use some javascript.

Comment: Good luck. Don't hesitate to ask a question if you run into a specific problem.

Comment: Tim, welcome to Stack Overflow. What you are trying to do is totally possible but you need to research it, you need to use Javascript so Google something like "Javascript Popup box" or similar. you can also look into javascript ***fancybox*** which may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how familiar you are with CSS and JS, but you can do 2 things:

1.
Use a div in the root of the body element, with `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`(Depending on your design and layout) and `z-index:-100` or whatever is needed to hide it, and then use JS or jQuery to change z-index to make it visible.

2.
Get the button to insert and remove the element into the DOM at root much like the first solution, from a string directly.

Comment: Thanks! I used JS to change the z-index after I made the div. It works now :D